# Oracle PLSQL script for string concatenation

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql

I have a database of SQL queries, procedures etc.

Now I have following SQL statement with concatenation operators.

```
'INSERT INTO TEST_TABLE(ID, NAME)' || 'SELECT ID, NAME FROM ' || ' MY_TABLE'
```

I want that when I get SQL back it return

```
INSERT INTO TEST_TABLE(ID, NAME) SELECT ID, NAME FROM MY_TABLE
```

This SQL is just for example but basically I want to remove concatenations and return simple SQL.

Thanks

Comment: just watch out for the SQL injection vulnerability!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If i got the question right your looking for something like an `eval` to make oracle evaluate the string with the concatenation marks.

Try something like this

```
declare
  concatenetaed_sql  varchar2(32000);
  result_Sql varchar2(32000);
begin
  concatenetaed_sql  := '''INSERT INTO TEST_TABLE(ID, NAME)'' || ''SELECT ID, NAME FROM '' || '' MY_TABLE''';
  execute immediate 'select ' || concatenetaed_sql  || ' from dual'
     into result_sql;
  dbms_output.put_line(result_sql);
end;
```

And the result

```
INSERT INTO TEST_TABLE(ID, NAME)SELECT ID, NAME FROM  MY_TABLE

PL/SQL procedure successfully completed.
```